# CircleCI Slack Orbs. How to mention a user in a Slack message on a CircleCI failure? (solved)

Tags: slack, circleci

The CircleCI slack orbs docs can be found here: https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/slack.  In the `only_notify_on_branch` example they show how you can manually hard code a user id into the notification template i.e.: `mentions: '<@U8XXXXXXX>` but if you try and add a variable in this place, e.g. `mentions: <@SLACK_USER_ID>` it will just print out the user id in the template not actually mention the user

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

This answer works when using the inbuilt CircleCI slack templates like `basic_fail_1`, I don't know if it works when using a custom block.

Short version: 
Need to directly export a slack user id to the `SLACK_PARAM_MENTIONS` variable (CircleCI templates recognise this environment variable): `echo "export SLACK_PARAM_MENTIONS='<@$SLACK_USER_ID>'" >> $BASH_ENV`. This needs to be done in a job step before any step that could fail.

Longer version and code: 
In the `.circleci/config.yml` file you will have access to a `$CIRCLE_USERNAME` variable which will be the committer's bitbucket/github username. This needs to be mapped to a user id for all user's that you want to be notified on a failure. A user's slack id can be found on their slack profile in the desktop app.

```
jobs:
  build_app:
    ...
    steps:
      - ...
      - map_circle_to_slack
      - run: yarn install
      - run: yarn build
      - slack/notify:
          event: fail
          channel: '<slack-channel-id>'
          template: basic_fail_1
```

```
commands:
    map_circle_to_slack:
        steps:
          - run:
              name: Map circle username to slack user id
              command: |
                case $CIRCLE_USERNAME in
                              'user1-bitbucket-or-github-username')
                                  SLACK_USER_ID='user1-slackid'
                                    ;;
                              'user2-bitbucket-or-github-username')
                                  SLACK_USER_ID='user2-slackid'
                                    ;;
                              'user3-bitbucket-or-github-username')
                                    SLACK_USER_ID='user3-slackid'
                                      ;;
                                *)
                          esac
                echo "export SLACK_PARAM_MENTIONS='<@$SLACK_USER_ID>'" >> $BASH_ENV
```